# Oracle regex replace issue

Tags: regex, oracle, regexp-replace

I have one oracle table with one of the columns having below values,

```
,21A,22,21,28,28
```

I want to do a regex replace for removal of ,21 (The exact match) but it removes the value from ,21A

Below is my query,

```
update STUDENT set SCORES = REGEXP_REPLACE(SCORE, ',21' , '', 1, 1) where STUDENT_ID = 1;
```

How can this be achieved? Any ideas?

Comment: @AlexanderDerck, This isn't working.

Comment: My bad apparantly oracle regex has no lookarounds. Can't you just check for `,21,` and replace with `,` instead of empty string then?

Comment: Can you fix the database design instead and save yourself other hassles down the road?  This column violates 1st normal form. If you are stuck with someone else's bad design I feel your pain.

Comment: @Gary_W, This is already implemented and running. Design change will trigger lot of other changes at this time.

Comment: Maybe `REGEXP_REPLACE(SCORE, ',21(,|$)' , '\1', 1, 1)` is enough? Or even ``REGEXP_REPLACE(SCORE, ',21(\W|$)' , '\1', 1, 1)``?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, you can use a `,21(\W|$)` regex. It matches `,21` that is followed with a non-word character or the end of string.

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(SCORE, ',21(\W|$)' , '\1', 1, 1)
```

[Here is how](http://keencod.in/?p=98) you can perform a whole word search and replace in Oracle SQL:

```
regexp_replace( 
    haystack
    , '(\W|^)(' || what_to_replace || ')(\W|$)'
    , '\1' || with_what || '\3'
    , 1
    , 0
    , 'imn'
)
```